# Display distinct label and the number of nodes corresponding to each label in descending order

Tags: neo4j

I want list of all distinct labels and count on each label to see how many nodes correspond to the specific label.

I have a query which makes a list of the labels and is counting the nodes corresponding to each label, I don't know how to make the list in descending order.

```
MATCH (n) RETURN distinct labels(n), count(*) ;
```

I expect a list of labels in descending order by count

This is the result of the query which I have, really close to what I need:
[image: This is the result of the query which I have, really close to what I need]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`APOC plugin`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) to get the statistics for your Neo4j Database.
To get the node counts for labels, you can use the `apoc.meta.stats` function.

Refer the following query:

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD labels
RETURN labels;
```